# Getting error when use ffmpeg to covert jpg to mov using DNXHD codec

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to covert jpg to mov. I am asked to use DNxHD 115 codec, and framerate is 24, so I wrote the below command:

```
ffmpeg -i my.jpg -r 24 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec dnxhd -b:v 115m -y test.mov
```

but it is throwing error:

```
[swscaler @ 0xefae40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[dnxhd @ 0xf1c580] video parameters incompatible with DNxHD. Valid DNxHD profiles:
[dnxhd @ 0xf1c580] Frame Size:1920x1080p; bitrate:175Mbps; pixel format:yuv422p10; framerate:24000/1001
[dnxhd @ 0xf1c580] Frame Size:1920x1080p; bitrate:185Mbps; pixel format:yuv422p10; framerate:25/1
[dnxhd @ 0xf1c580] Frame Size:1920x1080p; bitrate:115Mbps; pixel format:yuv422p; framerate:24000/1001
[dnxhd @ 0xf1c580] Frame Size:1920x1080p; bitrate:120Mbps; pixel format:yuv422p; framerate:25/1
[dnxhd @ 0xf1c580] Frame Size:1920x1080p; bitrate:175Mbps; pixel format:yuv422p; framerate:24000/1001
[dnxhd @ 0xf1c580] Frame Size:1920x1080p; bitrate:185Mbps; pixel format:yuv422p; framerate:25/1
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg(native) -> dnxhd(native))
Error while openig encoder for output stream #0：0 - maybe incorrect parameter such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I have tried all the options but no success.

Comment: Share full log. Probably related to pixel format.

Comment: @Gyan why would you say pixel format?

Comment: DNXHD has restrictions on acceptable pixel formats as well.

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
ffmpeg -i my.jpg -r 24000/1001 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec dnxhd -b:v 115m -y test.mov
```

If the above fails, the pixel format is unacceptable, so try

```
ffmpeg -i my.jpg -r 24000/1001 -pix_fmt yuv422p -s 1920x1080 -vcodec dnxhd -b:v 115m -y test.mov
```

Note that your input is a single image. So the output duration will be `1001/24000` s

Comment: Awesome! I tried many times, and I find that I should use 115000000 instead of 115m! Now it's working, thanks a million!

Comment: @Gyan Can you help me with this.?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924549/loop-an-overlay-semi-transparent-video-using-ffmpeg-in-android